# how to handle json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml

I am using worldweatheronline api to access weather data,when a request is send it response by sending data in json.I want to display the weather information in html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="in"></input>
<input type="hidden" id="keys" value="apikey"></input>
<button id="go">Search</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#go").click(function(){
 var apikey = $("#keys").val();
 var q = $("#in").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=' + apikey + '&q=' + q,
    success: function(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(obj);
    },
    });
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>weather app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather">
        <input type="hidden"  name="key" value="apikeyneeded"></input>
        <input type="text" name="q"></input>

        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
var apikey = jQuery('[name="key"]').val();
var q= jQuery('[name="q"]').val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=' + apikey + '&q=' + q,
    success: function(response){
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(obj);
    },
});
```

add this line into the `head` tag to include `jQuery`
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `JSON.parse` that way. At first you must make a request to that API, then get a response and finally use the parse `JSON.parse(response)`
if you are interested I can help you to manage this using jQuery to request the json.

Comment: can you explain how to do it in jquery

Comment: Check my answer, if it works, then I can help you to get values from the obj JSON object.

Comment: how to parse json data   @ Hovo

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax method to get the data from openweathermap api.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?key=apikey&q=delhi",
        dataType: "jsonp", //Handle ajax cross domain
        success: function (response) {
            //the response already parsed.

        }
    });
```